# Is querySelector supported by all browsers?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, selectors-api

I would like to know is **querySelector** supported by all browsers? is not what's alternate for it to use?

I have tested it with IE8, FF3, Chrome 4. Its fine for me. I do not have old browsers. So i would like to know if old browsers will give problem to me or not?

Comment: 2017 update: `querySelector()` is [very widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector).  Go ahead and use it!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

IE7< don't support it and IIRC IE8 has issues with namespaces. There's at least one more esoteric browser out there with major issues but I don't recall which it is.

Basically there is no unified expression-based DOM method, and absolutely your best bet is to use a library (the ubiquitous "use jquery" answer, but you should at least check out [Sizzle](http://github.com/jeresig/sizzle) if you have a problem with large libraries) because rolling your own is more effort than reasonably worthwhile (I speak from experience).

Comment: +1 for mentioning Sizzle, the little selector engine used by jQuery and Prototype

Comment: Another selector engine that's worth mentioning: [NWMatcher](http://javascript.nwbox.com/NWMatcher/). Sizzle claims "CCS3 Compliance" but has [known problems](http://dhtmlkitchen.com/?category=/JavaScript/&date=2010/09/09/&entry=JavaScript-Query-Engines).

Comment: 2016 update: **YES**, just use `document.querySelector()`! :)

Comment: @rinogo: No, SAP browser doesn't support it.

Comment: @StefanSteiger - I'm not familiar with SAP browser.  Do you have figures on the market share of this browser?  Nowadays (2017), `querySelector()` is [very widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector).

Comment: @rinogo: No - but SAP-Browser is very old. It's part of some SAP systems/extensions. Probably a very old Java embedded browser control.

Answer (score 9):

QuerySelector is supported on Firefox 3.1+, IE8+ (only in IE8 standards mode), and Safari 3.1+ browsers.

[supporting article](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/css_selectors_api.shtml)

Answer (score 2):

I tested it with FireFox - It is  perfectly work.
In IE there is a issue when you use the document with quirk mode (without using DOCTYPE HTML)

Try to use  in the HTML document

Answer (score 2):

You can check MDN for detail information.

```
| Feature       | Chrome |  Firefox (Gecko) | Internet Explorer | Opera | Safari (WebKit) |
| ------------- | ------ | ---------------- | ----------------- | ----- | --------------- |
| Basic support |   1    |  3.5             |   8               | 10    |   3.2           |
```

Answer (score 1):

The *best* alternative is to use a third-party library that abstracts all that nasty browser-specific code away, like YUI or jQuery (I'm not as familiar with Prototype et al, so I can't say for sure if it uses the `query*` methods [when available]).

Comment: PrototypeJS doesn't wrap the DOM with CSS query selection. It is more of an extension to JavaScript as it uses ID names as selectors. Example: <div id="customerOrders"> ~ $('customerOrders').